# IME options not working for Custom edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext, custom-keyboard, imeoptions

Here i create a custom edittext using the following code. Now i face a strange problem,when i try to put IME option to overide the enter button and change its functionality to send, i cant achieve that option. Somebody please help me with this.

```
public class CustomEditText extends EditText {

    public CustomEditText (Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public CustomEditText  (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public CustomEditText (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        System.out.println("kkeeueueueehu");
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
                && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            li_bootm.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            // Do your thing here
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }

}


//here is how i use it in my fragment


private CustomEditText messageEditText;
private LinearLayout liedittext;
```

in my onCreateView

```
liedittext = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.liedittext);
    messageEditText = new NoImeEditText(getActivity());
    liedittext.addView(messageEditText);

messageEditText.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        messageEditText.setHint("enter_message");
        messageEditText.setSingleLine(false);






 messageEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                        KeyEvent event) {

                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    // InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity()
                    // .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    // imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(messageEditText.getWindowToken(),
                    // 0);
                    doSave();
                    li_bootm.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

When i put

```
messageEditText.setSingleLine(false);
```

I IME option are not available, but when

```
messageEditText.setSingleLine(true);
```

IME options are avaiable, but i need multiple lines in my edittext

Here is my linear layout

```
<LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/liedittext"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" 
                    >
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you manage it to work?